How to conditionally transform a character using `attoparsec`?
Using the attoparsec library, I've written this function here:
satisfyMaybe :: (Char -> Maybe a) -> Parser a
satisfyMaybe f =
  (fromJust . f) <$> satisfy (isJust . f)

Which basically applies f to the next character, and if it's Just x, then returns x, else fails the parse.
The thing is, I can't work out how to write this without using potentially failing functions like fromJust. I believe my code above is correct anyway and will never fail, but I feel like I'm using the library wrong if I need an unsafe function just to conditionally apply a function to a character from the input text.
Is there a way to use the library to write this function without fromJust or similar incomplete functions?

Essentially we can replicate what satisfyWith :: (Word8 -> a) -> (a -> Bool) -> Parser a [Hackage] does [src]:

satisfyWith :: (Word8 -> a) -> (a -> Bool) -> Parser a
satisfyWith f p = do
  h <- peekWord8'
  let c = f h
  if p c
    then advance 1 >> return c
    else fail "satisfyWith"
{-# INLINE satisfyWith #-}


It thus first peeks the next word8' in case it satisfies the condition p c, it advances and returns c, otherwise it fails.
We thus can use this as:
import Data.ByteString.Internal(w2c)
import Data.Attoparsec.Text as DAT

satisfyMaybe :: (Char -> Maybe a) -> Parser a
satisfyMaybe f p = do
  h <- peekWord8'
  case f (c2w h) of
    Just r -> DAT.take 1 >> pure r
    _ -> fail "satisfyMaybe"

Were you actually able to get this to work?  In yet another example of the harm of developers keeping internals completely internal, advance appears to be available only in a hidden internal module (at least in attoparsec-0.14.4).  Also, it looks like Data.Attoparsec.Text.satisfyWith might be a better starting point, since it will be Unicode-safe.  (It, too depends on internal ensure and advance functions that are only exported by hidden modules, unfortunately.)

@K.A.Buhr: aarrgggh, good point! We can use take 1.

I haven't run this code but I would try something like this:
satisfyMaybe :: (Char -> Maybe a) -> Parser a
satisfyMaybe f =
  try $ do
    c <- anyChar
    case (f c) of
      Just x -> pure x
      Nothing -> fail $ cons c " does not satisfy"

